# Ruby on Rails nested resources undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I saw similar examples here. But it just doesn't work for me.
I want to create/submit an activity for post. There are several days under a post. And an activity is under a specific date. See models below.

Models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dayinposts
  has_many :activitys, :through => :dayinposts
end

class Dayinpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :activitys
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dayinpost
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :dayinposts  do
resources :activitys
  end 
end
```

rake routes

```
post_dayinpost_activitys GET /posts/:post_id/dayinposts/:dayinpost_id/activitys(.:format)          activitys#index
                         POST /posts/:post_id/dayinposts/:dayinpost_id/activitys(.:format)          activitys#create
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @post.dayinposts.each do |dayinpost| %>

<% dayinpost.activitys.each do |activity| %>
  <p>
  <b>Action:</b>
  <%= activity.action %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for([@post, dayinpost, dayinpost.activitys.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :action %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :action %>
  </div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

error

```
undefined method `post_dayinpost_activities_path' for #<#<Class:0x40cb6d8>:0x40c9890>
```

But I have saw it in the rake routes... 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct pluralization for "activity" is "activities".

In your `config/routes.rb` you have "activitys", which is wrong.

Comment: thanks so much! I didn't realize that pluralization is so important in ROR. I thought as long as I use activitys everywhere, it should be fine.

Comment: @user1495133 See the [Inflector class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) for more on how Rails does this.